# XCode 5.0.1: can you run automated UI scripts in Instruments?

Tags: ios, instruments, ui-automation, ios-ui-automation, xcode5.0.1

After upgrading to 5.0.1, I'm unable to run UI scripts and get the following message: An error occurred while trying to run the script.
Furthermore, recording (the bottom red button) doesn't work either.
Is it the only solution to wait for Apple to fix it? Is there a way to downgrade to 5.0?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i had the same problem, and you should look at this link:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/zucchini-discuss/fQNrfOTaIuU

this is what Thomas W. said, and it totally solved my problem:
"It is simple, just go into "~/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator". There is beside the folder 7.0 an folder named 7.0.3 and maybe 7.0.3-64. Simply remove the 7.0 folder and exec following command:

ln -s 7.0.3 7.0"

Hope it fix your problem!

Comment: Answers dependent on links are discouraged.

Comment: Thanks! In the meantime I've downloaded 5.0.2, and this bug is fixed there.

Comment: Hey James, thats why i quoted what Thomas said on google groups, cause anyone can see the answer here, and the proper credit is given to Thomas W.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem but none of the other answers worked. There was no 7.0 folder; I'm using 5.0.2 (didn't try 5.1 yet)

Eventually I **plugged in a device** and **ran my project on the iPod/iPhone** instead of the simulator and it worked perfectly.